# How to unsubscribe events in TornadoFX?

Tags: java, events, kotlin, unsubscribe, tornadofx

In TornadoFX I want to unsubscribe a custom event so that the receiver will never handle the unnecessary events again, and maybe avoid something like memory leaks, however, when I use the `unsubscribe<MyEvent>` method in my code it doesn't work at all. Here is the part of my code:

```
object MyEventObj: FXEvent(EventBus.RunOn.BackgroundThread)
class MyEventBus(val personlist:List<PersonOld>): FXEvent()
class MyController: Controller()
{
    init
    {
        subscribe<MyEventObj> {
            unsubscribe<MyEventObj> { 
                println("Unsubscribe event!") //unsubscrib event and make sure the next code just runs once, but never works!
            }
            println("Event has received!")
            val items = listOf(PersonOld("Name A", 20), PersonOld("Name B", 25))
            fire(MyEventBus(items))
        }
    }
}
```

So, what is the problem? And how to use `unsubscribe` in TornadoFX? Thanks for help me in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unsubscribe` function takes the event listener as it's only parameter. To be able to unsubscribe, you therefore need to save the listener as a member val so you can reference it. To make matters more interesting, you cannot reference `this` inside the listener itself, so you need to call out to another function to be able to unsubscribe successfully. Here is a complete example:

```
object MyEvent : FXEvent()

class MyView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        paddingAll = 100
        button("Fire!") {
            setOnAction {
                fire(MyEvent)
            }
        }
    }

    val myListener: (MyEvent) -> Unit = {
        alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Event received!", "This message should only appear once.")
        stopListening()
    }

    init {
        subscribe(myListener)
    }

    fun stopListening() = unsubscribe(myListener)

}
```

If it was possible to reference the listener from within itself we could have added an `unsubscribe()` call directly inside the listener, but that's not possible, at least not with Kotlin 1.0.

*EDIT:* We just added a `times = n` parameter to subscribe so you don't need to deal with unregistration yourself. By default your event listener will be triggered every time the event fires, but by passing `1`, you can unregistrer automatically after the first time. With this new feature, coming in TornadoFX 1.6.3, you can simply do this instead:

```
class MyView : View() {
    override val root = stackpane {
        paddingAll = 100
        button("Fire!") {
            setOnAction {
                fire(MyEvent)
            }
        }
    }

    init {
         subscribe<MyEvent>(times = 1) {
            alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Event received!", "This message should only appear once.")
        }
    }

}
```

*EDIT2:* TornadoFX 1.6.3 will also introduce an `EventContext` which the trigger operates on, so you will be able to do `unsubscribe()` inside the event listener from the next version. Then you can do this as an alternative to the `times` parameter:

```
subscribe<MyEvent> {
    alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Event received!", "This message should only appear once.")
    unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: That makes some code added and rewrote, and at last I got it! Thanks, it already works in my test code.

Comment: Great :) You might want to revisit it after 1.6.3 is released to further reduce the boiler plate :)

Comment: That's great!! I cannot wait for checking the new version and new features available soon, finally I can use it in my way...(∩_∩)